# Issues with class element CSS

Tags: html, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my code doesnt work in the browser. It shows up fine in dreamweaver but when I load it onto my server its like the class element isnt being read. If I put it in style format directly it works though. For example `<p style="color:red>bla</p>` shows blah as red but`<p class="red>bla</p>` with the class element setup properly doesnt work when up on the server and is like its just `<p>blah</p>`. I have verified it a ton of times and fixed all the issues I could figure out. It says I have a couple stray tags and I cant help but wonder if thats it but I couldnt find anything online about fixing the tags or any confirmation if thats really the problem. Im rather lost and after days of googling, problem solving, and just straight guessing at how to fix it im hoping someone will have some insight into whats wrong. This is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<!--links to the css sheet for all the style info-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">


<!--Change favicon.ico to the images folder-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>sophia videos</title>
<style>

/*
body {
    background-image:url(background2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
*/

a {
    font-size:22px;
)


.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;   
    color:#036;
}


.vid_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:left;
    color:#F6F; 
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left: 6em;
    width:40%;
    font-style: italic;

}

a.vid_list {
    color:#09F;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:normal;
}

.vid_h2 { 
    font-size:48px;
    color:#0C3;
    text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="text-align:center"><i>Sophia</i></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2 class="vid_h2">Videos</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="vid_list">
<h2>Family</h2>
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="/var/video/family/">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="//var/video/friends/">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/misc">Misc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/okinawa">Okinawa</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
</ol>

<h2>Friends</h2>
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="/var/video/family/">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="//var/video/friends/">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/misc">Misc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/okinawa">Okinawa</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
</ol>

<h2>Misc</h2>
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="/var/video/family/">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="//var/video/friends/">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/misc">Misc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/okinawa">Okinawa</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
</ol>

<h2>Okinawa</h2>
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="/var/video/family/">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="//var/video/friends/">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/misc">Misc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/okinawa">Okinawa</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
</ol>

<h2>Tokyo</h2>
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="/var/video/family/">Family</a></li>
    <li><a href="//var/video/friends/">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/misc">Misc</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/okinawa">Okinawa</a></li>
    <li><a href="/var/video/tokyo">Tokyo</a></li>
</ol>
</div>






<footer class="footer">May the force be with you.</footer>

<!--link to nav bar menu. Make last thing in body-->
<?php include "../menu.php";?>

</body>
</html>
```

The relevant CSS files for that are

style.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

/*
@font-face {
    font-family: "arizoniaregular";
    src: url("arizonia-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("arizonia-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("arizonia-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("arizonia-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("arizonia-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("arizonia-regular-webfont.svg#arizoniaregular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
*/

/*sophia header at top*/
h1 {
    color:#96F;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"arizoniaregular", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}

/*alters nav text*/
a {
    color:#090;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*alters nav location*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:right;
    color:#C3C;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    color:#036;
}
```

and menu.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

a {
    color:#090;
    font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:right;
    color:#C3C;
}
</style>

<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://testserver.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://testserver.com/dog/">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://testserver.com/cat">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://testserver.com/tree/">Files</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://testserver.com/test//">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

It took me a while to figure out how to post all of this code in the question box and get it to format everything properly. I hope it came out correctly and both my question and the way ive gone about asking it is understandable/appropriate. Any help or insight you can offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: menu.php should contain only the <nav> part (because it's included in the first file)

Comment: You have CSS styles inside .php and inside html and on external CSS file ... wich part isn't working? You have multiple overrides

Comment: You're missing a closing double-quote after the class name. The style case works by accident because it stops parsing when it sees the `>`.